# FBSDK and pod: Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, dyld

Here is the detail of the error I get after installing `pod` and `FBSDK`.

```
mkdir -p /Users/test/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testprg- 
dslznrhetlhbmagubrsifwixyqfj/Build/Products/Debug- 
iphonesimulator/testprg.app/Frameworks
rsync --delete -av --filter P .*.?????? --filter "- CVS/" --filter "- 
.svn/" --filter "- .git/" --filter "- .hg/" --filter "- Headers" -- 
filter "- PrivateHeaders" --filter "- Modules" 
"/Users/test/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testprg- 
dslznrhetlhbmagubrsifwixyqfj/Build/Products/Debug 
iphonesimulator/Bolts/Bolts.framework" 
"/Users/test/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testprg- 
dslznrhetlhbmagubrsifwixyqfj/Build/Products/Debug- 
iphonesimulator/testprg.app/Frameworks"
building file list ... done
Bolts.framework/
Bolts.framework/Bolts
Bolts.framework/Info.plist
Bolts.framework/_CodeSignature/
Bolts.framework/_CodeSignature/CodeResources

sent 269308 bytes  received 98 bytes  538812.00 bytes/sec
total size is 268944  speedup is 1.00
dyld: Library not loaded: 
/usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.7.dylib
Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/awk
Reason: image not found
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

Any thought why this happen? I tried cleaning the `DerivedData` and `clearing the build`. Also, I opened the `xcworkspace` file to build and run, but no luck :|

Comment: What is your XCode version ?

Comment: I'm using Xcode 10.1 and swift 4.2

Comment: I checked the directory `/usr/local/opt/readline/lib/` and there is no such a file `libreadline.7.dylib` but there is `libreadline.8.dylib`. How can I switch to use that version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue wasn't related to swift or xcode and neither FBSDK. It was related to readline and gawk version on mac. Reinstalling and installing those fixed the issue.

```
brew uninstall gawk
brew uninstall readline
brew install readline
brew install gawk
```

Hope this answer help others.